# New iTunes connect interface error "You must choose a build"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When trying to submit my new app to the app store, I noticed Apple has changed its website interface: after updating metadata and keywords and hitting "submit for review" I got the error "you must choose a build".

By looking into google I found no answer.

However, I noticed that there is a plus button next to the 'build' heading where you have to select a build. This button is hidden somehow similarly to game center where achievements can't be deleted just because of the padding which hides the delete button.

So anybody have any ideas or solution to this. Please help

Comment: Here's an actual timed submission ... 45 minutes **to the prerelease** section.  who knows after that :/  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26144339/294884

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to upload a **binary** for your new App. Then, you wait ~5-20 min while **processing** and select the **plus button** and select a **binary** and **save**. After that you may **Submit for Review**. If it takes longer than ~25 min try uploading the binary again.

Comment: FYI it's taking more than 10 minutes for me. It's been more than an hour and it still says the build is in the processing stage.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Try uploading again.

Comment: really helpful answer this is!! thanks to Mr. Hannes Sverrisson

Comment: And how long does it take before Apple review it again?

Comment: @Milan1111 even if you upload the same binary twice, only one will show up in your binary lists, it will not affect the review process, which as before nobody will now how long it takes.

Comment: @Kuldeep I think it´s much better UI and flow! The old one was outdated and I think that you will like it after using it a little more :)

Comment: @HannesSverrisson I am talking about the bugs/issues in the new system. Please review the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800614/how-to-remove-binary-from-prerelease-in-new-itunes-connect

Comment: @Kuldeep Yes your right there are some issues and it frustrated me a little in the beginning especially changing the Build. But, I hope they fix this soon.

Comment: @HannesSverrisson ...  I had to wait a long time for it merely to hit the "Prerelease" area ... madness!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26144339/294884

Comment: I did not have to wait even 5 mins, just changed a browser to Safari from Chrome and "+" button appeared.

Comment: @wzbozon Thanks, but I don´t think changing browsers changed anything. When I wrote this I think a lot more developers where submitting Apps, so the workload may be less on the servers now.

Comment: USE SAFARI like it says...of course I've used Chrome to submit apps since ios4, but hey force me to launch Safari (which promptly crashed)

Comment: The real problem is that the plus button is not obvious and there is no feedback about what is going on

Comment: This waiting time is crazy. I can't believe but Apple managed to complicate a fairly easy and simple upload.

Comment: I have been waiting for more than 24 hours. Still, it is in processing mode

Comment: @Pushpa upload the binary again

Comment: My binary isn't even in the "processing" stage; it just doesn't show at all on iTunes Connect. Been more than an hour...

Comment: @NicolasMiari Then upload the binary again. They may be doing some update or work on the servers which might slow things.

Comment: In the end, I used Application Loader and it worked right away.

Comment: My latest upload took >4hours for "processing"... and we do have September 2018 not stone-age...!

Comment: @iKK I think there is high load in the app store now as everyone is preparing for the new sizes of phones

Answer (score 23):

I uploaded a binary and still I cannot choose it.

When I clicked on <kbd>Prerelease</kbd> I could see that the binary is listed and when I pointed to the <kbd>?</kbd> it says

> After builds are uploaded they will go through a processing status before they can be used.

So I guess Apple has introduced a new step into the process, and we must wait for it to complete.

Comment: Great I see it there, hoping it will eventually be available for upload. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Ok mine became available after an hour or so. It did give me an error because I had uploaded two of the same builds (from Xcode and Application Loader) as I was worried it was a bug in Xcode, but I could still select the build even though I got that error.

Comment: Mine is Processing for almost 24 hours now - well done apple!

Comment: Why don't they show this on the Versions tab. Not obvious that you have to click this to see status. And status in Xcode6 shows blank instead of submitted even though it submitted and said OK!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue: The `Add` link was not visible using Firefox v32. My solution might work for others as well:

1. Inspect the DOM with your browser developer tools and locate the anchor element in the DOM with the inner text `Add`.
2. For this anchor elmenent, remove all classes (text in the element's class attribute, that is), in order to make the element visible in the browser.
3. Click the add link.
4. Choose the binary you've (probably) already uploaded.
5. Click save in the top right corner, then Submit for review.

Pretty hard core that you have to hack the DOM in order to submit an app!

Comment: Seems that they have some UI issues - I also can't see the "Add" button on Safari; also the version "tab" links appear and disappear when I scroll up and down the page.

Comment: This helped me. I removed `ng-hide` from the class and the plus button appeared.

Answer (score 6):

After you submit your binary to iTunesConnect it goes into "Processing" state. At some point (e.g. 30 minutes for me), it becomes validated and ready to use (assuming no validation problems). Next, you go to the Builds section of the app on iTunesConnect and click the "+" to select your latest build as the current build for your app.  THEN, you can submit for review.

Answer (score 3):

Try safari browser. I faced the same problem when I was trying to upload from Chrome.

Comment: Your "answer" should be a comment.

Comment: It took 7 hours for me.  Uploaded my build at 4 o'clock and it didn't finish processing until 11 oclock.  I guess if your lucky it will finish in 10 minutes....

Comment: This is a correct answer for me as well. I did not have to wait even 5 mins, just changed a browser to Safari from Chrome and "+" button appeared. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

scroll down window you will see build header select your uploaded build wait for moments it will enable the save option save and then click submit thats all

Answer (score 1):

The chances are you just need to wait for the new build to pass the 'Validation' process. If you go to the new 'prerelease' tab in itunes connect, you can see the status of your new build. Wait until it's ready, and then go back to Versions tab and the + sign will be available next to the Builds section.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Connect have scrapped the "Waiting For Upload" state. The first sate is now "Prepare for Submission" and the next "Waiting For Review": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html

Both meta-data and binary upload are handled in "Prepare for Submission". When you're ready with both you Submit for Review.

Answer (score 1):

Just visiting the Prerelease tab and then navigating back to the Versions tab for some reason then displayed the "+" symbol on the Build section.

I waited ~45 minutes to see if it would happen automatically, but that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just a call out.  Make sure that your package identifier i.e. (com.companyname.appname) is correct for the app you are uploading.  I just wasted 2 days wondering why my build wasn't showing up because I had a typo in my bundle identifier.

Thanks and have a wonderful day.

Comment: How can you sign and upload a binary with the wrong bundle identifier? Xcode should match the archive with an iTunesConnect entry before being able to upload...?

Answer (score 1):

as this screenshot shows:

[image]

you have to wait for the binary to be processed and activated before you can select it..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After uploading a new build, the one I wanted to submit for release, I could d not see that build on the versions tab. It was showing up on the prerelease tab. Here is how I got it to show up on the versions tab so that I could submit it for review:

1. Hover over the old build and press the red circle with a minus to delete the old build.
2. Having done that, the + option now appeared. Select that.
3. Now select the build you want to release.

After that, you can submit that build for review.