# In the new iTunes connect interface - how to change Prepare for Upload

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My new app version is currently stuck at Prepare for Upload. How do I change it? In the older interface I could do this - click Manage Your Apps, click your app, scroll down and click View Details. At the top right, click Ready to Upload Binary.

But, I don't know how to do it in new interface. Am I doing anything silly?

Comment: This state does not exist anymore, you can just go ahead and upload your binary in the prepare for submission state.

Comment: thank you @borrden. Is there any documentation for this change?

Comment: Not explicitly, but the state is now missing from the current documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html and others have noted as well that this is how they are doing it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704171/new-itunes-connect-interface-error-you-must-choose-a-build

Comment: Please check the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816828/app-submission-binary-does-not-show-up-in-itunesconnect/25816865#25816865